# Aggregate with unique ID and columns

Tags: r, aggregate

I have ID's with data per year, but the years are repeated throughout the columns:

```
test1<-data.frame(
  ID=c("P1","P1","P2","P2","P1","P2","P1","P1") , 
  YEAR1 =c(10,30,50,40,50,45,12,8), 
  YEAR2=c(40,20,30,10,50,30,60,10), 
  YEAR3=c(300,200,170,150,150,120,90,100), 
  YEAR2= c(100,10,20,30,50,60,40,80))
```

and what I need to sum the data per year and get something like this:

```
result <- data.frame(
  ID=c("P1","P2") , 
  YEAR1 =c(110,135), 
  YEAR2=c(460,180), 
  YEAR3=c(840,440))
result
#  ID YEAR1 YEAR2 YEAR3
#1 P1   110   460   840
#2 P2   135   180   440
```

I've tried it with `aggregate`:

```
result <- aggregate(test1, by=list(test1$ID), FUN = sum)
```

But my problem is that does not sum the years that are equal, maybe is because years now is an attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option in `base R` would be to split the data in to `list` of data.frames based on the similarity in column names and do the `aggregate` within the `list` and `Reduce` by `merge`ing with the common 'ID' column

```
lst1 <- lapply(split.default(test1[-1], 
     sub("\\.\\d+$", "", names(test1)[-1])), function(x) 
     aggregate(.~ ID, cbind(test1[1], colN = unlist(x)), sum))
lst1 <-  Map(function(x, y, z) setNames(x, c(y, z)), lst1, "ID", names(lst1))

Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by = "ID"), lst1)
#    ID YEAR1 YEAR2 YEAR3
#1 P1   110   460   840
#2 P2   135   180   440
```

---

Also, if there is only a single column that is duplicated,, then just do

```
transform(aggregate(.~ ID, test1, sum), YEAR2 = YEAR2 + YEAR2.1)[-5]
#   ID YEAR1 YEAR2 YEAR3
#1 P1   110   460   840
#2 P2   135   180   440
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
test1 %>% 
  gather(key = "yr", value = "value", -ID) %>% 
  mutate(yr = str_remove(yr, "\\.\\d+")) %>% 
  group_by(ID, yr) %>% 
  summarize(value = sum(value))

  ID    yr    value
  <fct> <chr> <dbl>
1 P1    YEAR1   110
2 P1    YEAR2   460
3 P1    YEAR3   840
4 P2    YEAR1   135
5 P2    YEAR2   180
6 P2    YEAR3   440
```

The gather operation creates a modified data frame with three columns: ID, year, and value. Then you can modify the year column to remove the `.1`, `.2` etc. from the duplicate column names and perform a summary operation to get the totals by ID and year.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the first part of the column names (except for `ID`), you can subset the relevant columns, add the rows together, and then use `tapply` to sum the resulting value by `ID`.

```
nms = names(test1)[-1]
nms = split(nms, sapply(strsplit(nms, "\\."), "[", 1))
sapply(nms, function(nm){
    tapply(rowSums(test1[nm]), test1["ID"], sum)
})
#   YEAR1 YEAR2 YEAR3
#P1   110   460   840
#P2   135   180   440
```